# If a signal is periodic, can the error of approximation by Discrete Fourier Transform be avoided when using finite number of samples?

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

As title says, if a signal $f(t)$ is periodic, can approximation errors of approximation by discrete Fourier transform (DFT) be avoided when only finite number of samples are used?

Comment: Truncation errors of approximation refers to the fact that you ignore very high frequency components of the signal, right?

Comment: No. I just mean any error when using finite samples.

Comment: No, periodic just means you don't need to worry about the noise introduced because the start and end don't 'match'. Roughly, any real signal can be made periodic by tapering quickly near the start and end of the period. You need some limits on bandwidth. For example, if you sample $\sin$ fast enough (which is periodic) you will get a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In the case of periodic signals, the Fourier transform is a Dirac comb corresponding to the Fourier decomposition of the function with respect to its period. Most functions will have infinitely many nonzero Fourier coefficients, so any finite sampling will necessarily involve approximating.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the answer is no, but *if* the signal is band-limited, it can be represented by a finite number of samples. Example: take a sine wave; it is completely characterized by 3 samples.